# How to set up magento landing page?

Tags: url

Currently I have home page www.example.com. But now, I want to set landing page before the home page and the url of the landing page will become www.example.com and the url of the home page will become www.example.com/home. So, the basic structure will be.

### Current structure

URL to the home page: www.example.com

### The structure I would like to change

URL to the landing page: www.example.com
URL to the home page when the block/image on the landing page is clicked: www.example.com/home

Comment: hey.. once visit landing then second time ,landing page is not came..?

Comment: yes, Amit Bera, landing page will come as long as it is www.example.com. landing page will come first. And when the block on the landing page is clicked then will go to the home page and the url is www.example.com/home

Answer (score 2):

And what is the problem? Just set the homepage in backend to some CMS page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this Magento Landing Builder Extension, [Goomento - Magento Page Builder](https://github.com/Goomento/PageBuilder), it's free and compatible builder to any stores, build your landing page in just drop-and-drop to canvas.